How to link object rotation to an image sequence?
https://www.instagram.com/p/C6O9QKzyvCX/
^^ I am trying to emulate this. The artist rotates a block and as it rotates the image changes alongside it to match the rotation of the block.
My thinking is that I can copy the z rotation as a driver from the cube object, but i dont know where to paste that in order to link it with my image sequence. Comments under the post suggest using shape keys, the issue is changing textures doesn't make a new shape key.
Please point me in the right direction!

Can you please upload the reference image/video somehow?

Hello and welcome Ben Newtown,
there is many solutions to achieve this effect. I propose one solution with the version 4,2a of blender and the new Ray Portal BSDF node and a bit of Geometry Nodes.

Because classing correctly the images is a bit tedious, I propose just a 6 images solution but you can easily use the same method with more images, you just have to change the angle values accordingly to the sphere definition in Geometry Nodes.
First you have to import your images as plans and listed them in a new Collection, the order of the list is important and you will have to reorder them.
Add a plan (here called images) and add a Geometry Nodes to it. Delete the Input Group and add a UV Sphere Mesh. The definition of this sphere will determine the numbers of images you will use and the angles of rotation, here I keep it simple  with a definition of 4 by 2 in order to set my 6 Images on each points of the sphere.
I add my Ctrl Cube to the G.N. and Separate XYZ the rotation of it. I snap the X and Y angles on what I need (here pi/2) but before I add the half of this angle in order to have the snapping at the correct angle here pi/4. Then I Combine XYZ and I put it on the Angles input of a Transform Geometry nodes.
Its time to introduce Collection info of your collection of plans. You Instance on Points your sphere then instance your collection with pick instances (with Separate Children and Reset Children).

You will have now to reorder your collection in order to set the positions correctly on the sphere. A Viewer node on an index is very useful to do that.
We are practically good to go we just have to add a plan with a Ray Portal BSDF shader With an Object of the Texture Coordinate on the Position and a Combine XYZ with the Z to -1 in order to have an orthographic projection.

That’s it. Be aware that this shader only works in Cycle.
The 4.2a Blend.

Edit :
Another solution that works with the actual version of blender and not only in Cycles, use a bit more of G.N.
To the previous solution I just add an empty in order to place the image/plan where I want. Use a Compare node in order to select the lower plan.

And the 4.1 blend.


thanks sm you rule
